# Axis Error unable to engage module addressing

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, apache-axis

I am using axis2 on Apache Tomcat. I am writing client side to consumer SOAP WS. I configured Eclipse to use Tomcat as a server and while executing that line

```
stub._getServiceClient().engageModule("addressing");
```

I was getting that error "unable to engage module addressing". To fix that issue I add following line in the VM arguments of run configuration

```
-Daxis2.repo="E:\axis2\repository"
```

Now I export my project as a war file and deploy it on the real server. But Now I am again getting the same error(I checked the log file). I don't know how to fix, can every one help me. Thanks

Comment: Do you have the address.mar in your assembly? Or in the axis2 repo?  http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/axis2/addressing/

Comment: Yeah, I have address.mar file in E:\axis2\repository\module directory. I am not getting this error in development because I have added following parameter -Daxis2.repo="E:\axis2\repository" in run configuration.

Comment: Do you have an axis repo defined at runtime? Have you included the axis artifacts in your war?

Comment: No I didn't do something this. I just export the project as a war file and place it in webapps folder of tomcat.

Comment: I also create a setenv.bat file and add following line to add run time arguments
set "CATALINA_OPTS = -Daxis2.repo=E:\axis2\repository"
but it don't work

Comment: I solve my issue with this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526012/how-do-i-use-ws-addressing-properly-in-an-axis2-client

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved on my side in the following way:

I had an outdated WEB-INF/modules/axis2-jaxws-mar*.mar or rather 2 versions of it and the classloader got the older one of it and AxisServlet didn't start altogether

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.getGlobalModules()Ljava/util/List;
         at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.module.JAXWSModule.registerGlobalModule(JAXWSModule.java:51)